# How can I put @media queries into HTML?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;height:850px">
```

How can I put @media queries in there? I tried in CSS but it does not work. I think it would be easier if I put it in the HTML body tag.

Comment: `@media`  is css not html https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 1390px) {
                body {
                         height: 630px;
                     }
           }

Comment: is this not working because I have overflow-x:hidden in my body tag?

Comment: Please edit your question to add relevent code instead of posting it as a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make `@media` queries work you need to put a `<meta>` viewport tag in the head, like this:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

If you do that `@media` queries should work in either a seporate CSS stylesheet or through `<style>` tags.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 4):

You can inline css styles by using the `style` tag.

```
<body>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
     .body {
       background-color: red;
     }
    }
  </style>
</body>
```